# Removing print from keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Did anyone succeed in removing all print from an Apple keyboard? I would like to do this in a clean way, not involving stickers or paint that changes the feel of the keys. Might it perhaps be possible somehow to rub it off, using a chemical or a tool? (I want to do this primarily because it would be aesthetically pleasing; any solution less than perfect would therefore be inferior to doing nothing.)

Answer (score 1):

It took me 7 years to type off the text from enough keys to irritate me on my last keyboard. By that time the surfaces were completely smooth & shiny.

Simple extrapolation would tell me the 'text' is mounded into the plastic in a different colour, not a cheap screenprint that can be 'washed' off.

Comment: Yeah. so maybe one could use some kind of polishing tool.

Comment: One of your concerns was 'changing the feel of the keys' which polishing over time certainly does. It takes away that slightly 'grippy' matt surface they have when new. I'm certainly enjoying my identical, but new keyboard more than I did the old shiny one.